# Is there a way to populate the Tree component with the display list

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4

Is there a way display the display list in the `Tree` component. I could parse the display list into xml but then I would not be able to create a reference to the display object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list to fill a tree if the objects in your list have a `parent` property, to specify which object is their parent. Otherwise you can't know how to position them in the tree.